# Different data for different user agent with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to make my Nodejs app for different user agents(Web, iOS, Android) with different data(i.e filter field for certain user agent). Should I do different route for each or put in the same route and conditioning user agent? If I have to do in same route, which node module you recommend me?

Comment: app.get('/test', function(req, res,next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same route and [`useragent`](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/useragent) package to parse the `req.headers['user-agent']` (`express`) variable.

Example:

```
const useragent = require('useragent')
// ...
const ua = useragent.is(req.headers['user-agent'])

if (ua.firefox) {
 // firefox stuff
} else if (ua.chrome) {
 // chrome suff
}
```